# Access adapter unprotected data from a secured app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Im working in a hybrid mobilefirst 6.3 app, and i want to access to an adapter previous to my login, is there a way that i can do that? because every time that i want to access my adapter the handleChallenge method occurs.

application-descriptor.xml:

```
 <android version="1.0" securityTest="NevadaApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
```

my adapter config xml:

```
<procedure name="getPhoneNumber" securityTest="wl_unprotected"/>
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the security test in application-descriptor.xml?

Comment: the WL.Client.connect goes through the onConnectSuccess without checking previous login, and i want the app to connect on start

Comment: That does not answer my question. Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set a security test also on the application level, meaning on the environment in application-descriptor.xml, you will get hit with a challenge handler despite having the adapter procedure set with a security test set as wl_unprotected.

To achieve what you're looking for you will need to add security tests to your adapter procedures (with the one you want unprotected as wl_protected), and leave the environment without a security test assigned to it in application-descriptor.xml.

- Read more on security tests here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en
- Read more on the different authentication options here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/